Empty DataGridView cells after binding to List<T>
I am binding a List to DataGridView:
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private class LogEntry
    {
        public DateTime TimeStamp;
        public string Message;
    }

    List<LogEntry> _logEntries = new List<LogEntry>();

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EentArgs e)
    {
        grid1.DataSource = _logEntries;
    }

    public void AddCommItem(string msg)
    {
        _logEntries.Add(new LogEntry { TimeStamp = DateTime.Now, Message = msg });
    }
}

It doesn't matter how do I bind the list to the grid, through BindingSource or directly, the result is always the same:
The grid shows as many rows as the list has items, but all cells are displayed as NULL values.
How to make the grid to display data in the cells?

Use Properties instead of Fields in LogEntry. That's a good practice for almost everything in Net. If its public use a Property and only for internal/private stuff use fields.

And that the class is private might also be a problem.

As mentioned, you need Properties, not Fields. If the collection is initially empty, you prefer a BindingList instead of a simple List (you know, collection change notifications)

You are right. As soon as I converted fields to properties, it started to work. Private class was not the problem.
